# Focus on the controls in the Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I have four controls in the Windows phone page. When i press enter in the KeyBoard , i want the foucs to be moved to the next available control in that page. We can achieve that through hooking of KeyDown events for all the controls. Is there any simple way to achieve in 100% xaml code in Windows Phone?

Comment: No, xaml doesn't provide a way to do this. I would also question why you want to employ this type of design on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. You would need to have some kind of logic in the XAML that would achieve that. In other declarative languages like QML this is possible but sadly XAML does not provide this kind of programmatic logic.

Well one thing that you can always do is write your own control where you expose a DependencyProperty for the target control to receive the next focus when the current one loses it. Then you can have an entirely 100% XAML solution. But, that effort is too much and not worthwhile unless you are going to have this kind of need many times in the app or in several apps.